# NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS in Oracle's to_char() function

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I'm trying to convert numeric field to varchar.

```
select value from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

returns ','

code is:

```
select to_char(sm.trxn_amount, '999999999999D000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
```

`sm.trxn_amount` format is NUMBER(18,3)

for example, lets run this code

```
select sm.trxn_amount
from x
```

result is 106729,000

if i then run

```
select 
to_char('106729,000', '999999999999D000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
from dual
```

result is

> 106729,000

but if i run

```
select to_char(sm.trxn_amount, '999999999999D000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''')
```

result is

> 106729.000

what am i missing? cant get decimal point to be ','

Comment: Can you clarify what your first query returns - ',' doesn't make sense. If it's ',.' then the third and fourth queries would both show commas. And if it's '.,' then the fourth would still show a comma, but the third would throw ORA-01722 invalid number. So something doesn't add up in what you're showing (hence your question!). Are all those queries and results exactly what you use and see? Which client are you running this in, and how (e.g. script vs. statement), and is your client applying formatting to the number result (e.g. via set numf or equivalent in your client) from the second query?

Answer (score 0):

If that column's datatype is `NUMBER`, then it most probably doesn't have trailing zeros (behind the decimal point).

Anyway, it seems that everything is fine on my 11g:

```
SQL> create table sm (trxn_amount number(18, 3));

Table created.

SQL> insert into sm values (106729);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from sm;

TRXN_AMOUNT
-----------
     106729

SQL> select to_char(sm.trxn_amount, '999999999999D000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') result from sm;

RESULT
-----------------
       106729,000

SQL>
```